# Getting all items in a list that have a property set to the same value

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, list

Say I have a list, `List<Foo> SomeList`, and `Foo` is a class that has two properties, `Bar` and `Baz`.

Is there a LINQ query that will allow me to select all the items of type `Foo` that share the same value for `Bar`, so they can be processed together?

Something like:

```
foreach (List<Foo> foos in SomeList.SelectBy (x => x.Bar))
{
// process foos
}
```

so that all the `Foo` items with `Bar = 0` are processed first, then those with `Bar` set to 1, and so on and so forth.

Can this be done easily, or do I need to write that functionality myself?

Comment: did u mean like  SomeList.orderby(x => x.Bar)

Comment: So you need essentially a `Count(x.bar) > 0` and an `order by` if I'm reading this through my head in SQL terms correct?

Comment: `SomeList.GroupBy(x => x.Bar).OrderBy(x => x.Key)`

Comment: See this : [Group By](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That you need is to group by first and then order by the key the items in your list.

```
var grouped = SomeList.GroupBy(item => item.Bar)
                      .OrderBy(gr=>gr.Key);


foreach (var item in grouped)
{
    // item has a Key property associated with the value of Bar
    // You can take the list of Foo by simply calling this
    // item.ToList() and then you can process this.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, so that i go for a wild guess. hope that you are looking for something like the following:

```
 List<Foo> SomeList = new List<Foo>();
        SomeList.Add(new Foo() {Bar=1,Baz ="ASDASD"}); 
        SomeList.Add(new Foo() {Bar=2,Baz ="dqwe"});
        SomeList.Add(new Foo() { Bar = 5, Baz = "fsdfsgsdg" });
        SomeList.Add(new Foo() { Bar = 5, Baz = "dghjhljkl" }); 
      foreach(Foo f in  SomeList.Where(x=>x.Bar==5).ToList())
      {
      // do some operations
      }
```

> It allows you to select all the items of type Foo that share the same
>   value for Bar(here it is `5`, make it dynamic if needed)

As per **Christos's** suggestion you can apply `OrderBy` if the order is important.